# How to generate a random number between min and max in linux KERNEL

Tags: c, random, linux-kernel

I need to get a number in a certain range in linux **kernel**. Min number **30** max **5000**. It should not be a one-time function.

I have working code which works in linux(not kernel):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define max_ppm 5000
#define min_ppm 30
int get_ppm_value()
{
   srand(time(NULL));
   int ppm_value;
   ppm_value= (rand() % (max_ppm + 1 - min_ppm)) + min_ppm; 
   return ppm_value;
}
```

This works great and every time gives me a new desired number.

**Question:**

1. The first question is theoretical
   why can't I use the C libraries in the kernel (stdlib). In addition to the answer, the speed of execution and the amount of code.
2. How can I do it better in the kernel?  using the get_random_bytes() function (use it also i.e.(`get_random_bytes() % (max_ppm + 1 - min_ppm)) + min_ppm)`) or from */dev/random* or */dev/urandom*
3. is there an alternative to this library #include <stdlib.h>

This is very serious for me, so I ask you to also treat my question as well.

Comment: "This works great and every time gives me a new desired number." --> I doubt that.  Function has `srand(time(NULL));` which will cause `rand()` to form the same random number if `get_ppm_value()` is called in the same _second_.  Better to call `srand()` once - ever .  Perhaps in `main()`?

Comment: checked 15 times in a row and each time a new number

Comment: Where those 15 calls to `get_ppm_value()` in the same clock second?

Comment: `int i; get_random_bytes(&i, sizeof i); ppm_value= (i % (max_ppm + 1 - min_ppm)) + min_ppm;`

Comment: @tshiono I suspect  `i % (max_ppm + 1 - min_ppm)` will return values in the [-4970 ... + 4970] range when only [0...4970] needed.  Perhaps use _unsigned_ math?

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica yes      unsigned int rand;

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica thanks for the time correction

Comment: "why can't I use the C libraries in the kernel (stdlib)." --> Hmmm, if the kernel calls `srand(), rand()`, would not that change the results seen by a user's application calls to `rand()` in a non-deterministic way?

Comment: **1.** Isn't it obvious? How can you use libraries in the kernel which are dependent on the environment that dependend to the kernel being already up and running? **2.** No files should be used in the kernel. What you want is to find the proper interface (API) for you needs. **3.** No. The kernel (in any OS) has unique set of APIs that one must use.

Comment: You can also use `get_random_int()`, which I expect will be slightly faster than `get_random_bytes`

Comment: @Hasturkun and it works similar?

Comment: It returns a random 32 bit unsigned int, and won't do as much work as `get_random_bytes` needs to. It doesn't have backtracking protection, but given that you were using `rand()` above, I doubt that's an issue for you.